# How to wrap a templated function to work on const and non-const data

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I want to create a templated function that works the same way for const and non-const data, except that it returns a const or non-const pointer as appropriate.

For instance, I want to return a pointer to a matching element in a container:

```
template <class Container, class Pred>
typename Container::value_type* getValuePtrIf(Container& c, Pred pred)
{
    auto it=std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), pred);
    return (it!=c.end()) ? &(*it) : nullptr;
}
```

However I can't get this to build for const and non-const calls.  If I omit the const from the `Container& c` declaration then it can't return a const pointer, but if I change to `const Container& c` then I can return a const pointer, but then the non-const case doesn't build.

Is there a way of defining this so that the `const` is interpreted as being part of the `Container` template parameter so that I only have to define one version of this function?

Comment: Why do you need non-const while you don't modify `c` ?

Comment: I want a version that returns a const pointer and one that returns a non-const pointer

Comment: @MM because he wants a pointer to non-const as return value if the Container is modifiable

Comment: C++11: `template<class C, class P> auto getValuePtrIf(C& c, P pred) -> decltype( &*c.begin() );`

Comment: @DyP: That did it! Please make it an answer and I'll accept it. Is this something that can only be done with decltype?

Comment: @the_mandrill Just accept Arne's answer ;)

Comment: @DyP just came up with the same ;)

Comment: Oh well, you'll just have to settle for the kudos then!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the code it seems you have C++11 support in your compiler. Then you can probably use `decltype` and trailing return types as well:

```
template <class Container, class Pred>
auto getValuePtrIf(Container& c, Pred pred) -> decltype(&*std::begin(c))
{
    auto it=std::find_if(std::begin(c), std::end(c), pred);
    return (it!=std::end(c)) ? &(*it) : nullptr;
}
```

`it` will be of whatever type `std::begin(c)` gives you (`iterator` or `const_iterator`), so the type of `&(*it)` is the same as of `decltype(&*std::begin(c))`.

Comment: very clever. for the first time I really see the motivation for making C++ syntax even more elaborate than it already is.  Not to say that I think it's a great idea.  It's very unobvious what the intent is here.  This is not a criticism of the answer but really questions the idea of making C++ even more complex than it already is.  I question whether adding this kind of stuff to C++ really adds utility in proportion to the increased syntactic opacity.

Comment: @RobertRamey in C++14, the `-> decltype(&*std::begin(c))` will vanish, as the return type of the function is deducible for the compiler. The type will be the same.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest is to define both templates and let the compiler find the best match

```
template <class Container, class Pred>
typename const Container::value_type* getValuePtrIf(const Container& c, Pred pred)
{
    auto it=std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), pred);
    return (it!=c.end()) ? &(*it) : nullptr;
}
template <class Container, class Pred>
typename Container::value_type* getValuePtrIf(Container& c, Pred pred)
{
    auto it=std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), pred);
    return (it!=c.end()) ? &(*it) : nullptr;
}
```

If you object to duplicating code (a worth objection) due to maintenance issues you can try something like the following:

```
template <class Container, class Pred>
typename const Container::value_type* getValuePtrIf(const Container& c, Pred pred)
{
    auto it=std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), pred);
    return (it!=c.end()) ? &(*it) : nullptr;
}
template <class Container, class Pred>
typename Container::value_type* getValuePtrIf(Container& c, Pred pred)
{
    return const_cast<Container::value_type*>(
        getValuePtrIf(const_cast<const Container &>( c ), pred)
    );
}
```

If it were me, I'd also replace Pred with const Pred & pred)

Robert Ramey

Comment: My reason for the question was to avoid creating two different versions. Using two const casts I think is very unappealing.  Why do you think it's better to make the predicate argument const, given that the definition of `std::find_if()` itself takes one by value?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: lol - but two different versions is what you want!  One version returns one type (const Container::value_type *) and the other version returns a different type (const Container::value_type *).  There might be different syntax to accomplish this - but they would all amount to the same thing.  If you don't like const_cast - you can use the first method.  But note that the const_cast is being used here exactly as it was intended - to permit exactly this sort of thing. By using it you have exactly what you asked for (though maybe not what you want!).

Comment: I prefer using const Pred & p to using Pred p for a couple of reasons. a) Depending on the compile, passing my reference might avoid a superfluous copy.  b) it would permit passing a predicate that is non-copyable.  c) a mutable predicate might have surprising effects - perhaps returning different results depending on how find_if is implemented. - so I would just prohibit it with const.